# Because my sqlite database is deleted?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating an application with sqlite. But every time I close my computer the database is deleted. q may be happening? I have this code:

Table I at the beginning and so it appears commented

```
public class PerfilHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static String NOMBRE_TABLA = "Perfiles";
public static String CAMPO_ID = "id_perfil";
public static String CAMPO_COLOR = "color_perfil";

String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + NOMBRE_TABLA + " (" + CAMPO_ID + 
" integer primary        key autoincrement, " + 
        CAMPO_COLOR + " TEXT not null)";

public PerfilHelper(Context contexto, String nombre,
                           CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
//        db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnterior, int versionNueva) {

// db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NOMBRE_TABLA);
// db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
}
```

}

```
public static String cargarBaseDeDatosPerfil(Context context) {

String color = "";

    PerfilHelper perfil = new PerfilHelper(context, PerfilHelper.NOMBRE_TABLA, null, 1);

    SQLiteDatabase db = perfil.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] campos = new String[] {PerfilHelper.CAMPO_ID, PerfilHelper.CAMPO_COLOR};
    String[] args = new String[] {"1"};

    Cursor c = db.query(PerfilHelper.NOMBRE_TABLA, campos, null, null, null, null,  null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
              //String codigo= c.getString(0);
            color = c.getString(1);
         } while(c.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    return color;

  }
```

Comment: how does your computer relate to the andorid application? Do you run on emulator? What options do you use when starting this emulator?

Comment: If I make the table in the beginning everything works fine: insert, select ... but when I turn off the computer database is deleted from my computer. yes, i run on emulator ok

Comment: can you tell me how you run the emulator? Basically android databases are stored on the device (emulator in your case) not on computer, so probably you tell the emulator to run in some conservative way.

Comment: sorry but I do not know what you want to know exactly

Comment: When you start your AVD/Emulator, is 'Wipe user data' ticked in Launch Options (it should not be)? Are you creating a new AVD each time or using the same one? Are you using Eclipse or something else?

Comment: I always use the same AVD with Eclipse. wipe user data is not ticked in run configurations

Comment: From eclipse when you select to run emulator first a dialog box is displayed with several options, one of which is the above mentioned one. Most probably you do not start the emulator specifically, but please do it at least once - open avd manager and start the emulator. See if the option is ticked in the dialog box.

Comment: is not ticked in run configurations